# Ошибка при работе с файлами - "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

IDLE выдает ошибку такого плана:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/dodada8.py", line 26, in <module>
openFile.fileOpen(fileName)
File "C:/Python34/dodada8.py", line 11, in fileOpen
fileOpen = open("C:\file2_3.txt","w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\x0cile2_3.txt'
```

Вот код:

```
fileName = str(input("Choose of 3 files: file2_1, file2_2, file2_3: "))

class fileConnector:

   def fileOpen(self, fileName):
     if fileName in ("file2_1","file2_2","file2_3"):

       if fileName == "file2_1":
           fileOpen1 = open("C:\file2_1.txt","w")
       elif fileName == "file2_2":
           fileOpen1 = open("C:\file2_2.txt","w")
       elif fileName == "file2_3":
           fileOpen1 = open("C:\file2_3.txt","w")
     else:
       print("File name is wrong")



class fileWriter:

   def fileWrite(self):
        write_str = str(input("Type any message: "))
        fileOpen1.write(write_str)
        fileOpen1.close()



openFile = fileConnector()
openFile.fileOpen(fileName)

writeFile = fileWriter()
writeFile.fileWrite()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использование `\` вызывает экранирование символов с строках. Например: `\n`, `\t`.

Поэтому у вас `\f` стало `\x0c`.

Варианты решения:

- Используйте `raw`-строки: `r"C:\file2_1.txt"`
- Экранируйте слеш: `"C:\\file2_1.txt"`
- Используйте другой слеш: `"C:/file2_1.txt"`. Он не вызывает экранирование, поэтому безопасный
- Можно воспользоваться библиотекой `pathlib` для формирования пути через синтаксис:

  ```
  import pathlib
  path = pathlib.Path('C:/') / 'Windows' / 'System32' / 'Boot'
  print(path)  # C:\Windows\System32\Boot
  ```